# Changing div classes with Js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change classes of div with onclick, but there seems to be something wrong with my code because it doesn't work.

```js
function changeColorsDay() {
  document.getElementById("wrap").classList.toggle("Day", true);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

#wrap {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font: italic bold 15px arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: rgb(0, 14, 51);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-size: cover;
}

wrap.Day {
  background-color: rgb(240, 230, 232);
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <a href="#" class="Button">Home Page</a>
  <a type="button" class="Button" onclick="changeColorsDay()">Change</a>
</div>
```

What can I do to make it work?

Comment: Which element has the id `wrap`?

Comment: css style for id should have prefix #, i.e. #wrap.day

Comment: Vote close, is just typo error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i believe you missed the '#' in your css

```
#wrap.Day{
    background-color: rgb(240, 230, 232);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You mis a element with the id `wrap`. Also in your css you missed the `#` in front of `wrap.Day`.

I added a div with the id `wrap` and added the id selector. As you can see in the snippet it works perfectly.

```js
function changeColorsDay() {
  document.getElementById("wrap").classList.toggle("Day", true);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

#wrap {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font: italic bold 15px arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: rgb(0, 14, 51);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-size: cover;
}

#wrap.Day {
  background-color: rgb(240, 230, 232);
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <a href="#" class="Button">Home Page</a>
  <a type="button" class="Button" onclick="changeColorsDay()">Change</a>
</div>

<div id="wrap">day</div>
```